# ABS with both Navigation Drawer and DropDown Menu

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer

Does anybody know if you can use both `NavigationDrawer` (slideMenu, such as FourSquare) and `DropDown Menu`? I'm using `ActionBar Sherlock`, since I have to support versions from Android 2.3. 
First one, `NavigationDrawer` is to navigate among activities. About `DropDown Menu`, I want to use it to change the content of some lists.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  The NavigationDrawer and DropDown menu work independently of each other.

For the navigation drawer, you have to make your layouts use the drawerlayout and implement ActionBarDrawerToggle class.  For the dropdown menu, you just have to add the dropdowns to your actionbar.

What you want is to change is parent of your app's theme to whatever it is plus `.ForceOverflow`.  For example,

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow">
```

Unfortunately, in the newer versions of ABS, the ForceOverflow option has been removed, so in order to use this option, you will have to download an ActionBarSherlock version <= 4.1.0.

Comment: Do you have any reference where I can see it? I'm using an example that show an overflow menu icon (I still don't know how to manage its options), but it is hidden for Android 2.3. To see the example: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/  I would like to have something similar to this Google+ appearance: http://news.en.softonic.com/google-update-for-android-coming-today-new-navigation-drawer-notification-sync-and-more

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, your problem is that the overflow menu icon is not displaying on your Android 2.3 device.

With the latest version of ActionBarSherlock, this is the expected behavior, as Android 2.3 did not have the ActionBar/etc.  You will find your menu items on the bottom of the screen when you press the hardware "Menu" button, as you would in any other pre-Android-3.0 app.

You can force the overflow menu to work as it does on >3.0, but this will require a little fiddling with your project.  I'll post an explanation in the answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with that. But I suspect that it could harm my "Navigation Drawer" issue, right?

Comment: I doubt it, but if you run into any problems, let me know.